# Why do we define functions in instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

```
instance Functor Maybe where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
  fmap f Nothing = Nothing
  fmap f (Just item) = Just (f item)
```

If we define fmap outside the instance, we can still apply it to a Functor Maybe. Is there any purpose that we define it in the instance?

Comment: Typeclasses are typically used to define *ad hoc* polymorphism. So you can define all sorts of types to be `Functor`s, and then use `fmap` for all these types.

Comment: Why should I write `map_list` and `map_maybe` and `map_either` and `map_IO` etc, when I could just write `fmap` and write simple instances? This is why we use typeclasses.

Comment: Ok. So we define `fmap` in different kinds of Functors then it can be used for all Functors, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the idea is abstraction: write a general formula, then use it in general functions, which we can apply to specific situations. Monads are an example of this.

Comment: Yes, defining a function in a typeclass instance allows the type to be used in any function which requires that typeclass. So in your example, `Maybe` can be passed from any function which accepts a `Functor` as a parameter and can be returned from a function which declares its return type as `Functor a`.

Comment: By using type classes you introduce a discipline to all types those are the members of that type class. For instance Functor type class allows you to effect only a single type variable of a member type and what functions to define in an instance are basically predetermined.

Answer (score 1):

We define an instance of `Functor` typeclass for any type we want (that it makes sense) and then we can use the same-named function "`fmap`" for any of those types. The actual function will be different in each case, according to the actual type's implementation (aka "`instance`") of the typeclass (here, `Functor`)'s *methods* (here, just one method, named `fmap`).

Just like `+` for ints and complex numbers (and matrices, etc.) are two different functions, so is `fmap`. "Conceptually" it's the same but what it actually does is different in each case.

And if we define "fmap" outside of an instance, we can't redefine it later for another type - the name will be already taken. Only methods of typeclasses allow us to use the same name for related, but different, operations for various related, but different, types.